# (eclipse) Junit test not using cacert certificate from VM arguments - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, jvm, certificate

So I have a spring boot application that does API calls to an external URL through my companies proxy, we have a cert store file which allows us to access that site.In eclipse on the application I have "VM arguments" in "run configurations" as

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=http.proxy.mycompany.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8001 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts.jks
```

with the cacertsfile in the root of my project. This works fine in the spring app but in my JUnit tests that have the same VM arguments I get the error

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: What's the working directory for your JUnit launch configuration, is it the same as that of your Spring Boot app?

Comment: @nitind yes it is

Answer (score 0):

The trust store is useless if you don't provide a password (`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=the-password`) and your proxy settings should have no impact on whether your JVM trusts the certificate.  Your best bet is to update your JRE's `lib/security/cacerts` with something like:

```
keytool -import \
  -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/lib/security/cacerts
  -file /tmp/some-certificate.cer \ 
  -alias some-alias
```

and make sure Eclipse and the JUnit use that JRE.